# HEREDOC и NOWDOC -почему в одном случае ошибка, в другом нет?

Tags: php

```js
$var = 10;
$str = 'This is \'string\'. $var';

$str2 = "This is \"string\". $var";
// var_dump($str2);

$str3 = <<<HERE
This is "string". $var
HERE; 

$str4 = <<<'HERE'
This 'is' "string". $var
HERE;

echo $srt4;
```

Error: 
Notice: Undefined variable: str4 in D:\sites\mysite.local\www\rus\4\data types.php on line 42 ($str4 = <<<'HERE')

Notice: Undefined variable: srt4 in D:\sites\mysite.local\www\rus\4\data types.php on line 46 (echo $srt4;)

В этом варианте все работает:

```js
$var = 10;
$str = 'This is \'string\'. $var';

$str2 = "This is \"string\". $var";
// var_dump($str2);
// HEREDOC
// NOWDOC

$str3 = <<<HERE
This is "string". $var
HERE;

$str4 = <<<'HERE'
This 'is' "string". $var
HERE;

echo $str4;
```

Выводит: This 'is' "string". $var

Answer (score 0):

**Nowdocs** — это строки с одинарными кавычками, **Heredocs** — с двойными кавычками.

Nowdocs задается аналогично heredoc, но синтаксический анализ не выполняется внутри nowdoc.

Например:

```
$string = 'Я';

$here = <<<HERE
    Здесь был $string! // Выведет на экран Здесь был Я!
HERE;

$now = <<<'NOW'
    Здесь был $string! // Выведет на экран Здесь был $string!   
NOW;
```

Comment: это понятно, в чём разница. у меня вопрос в другом: почему в моих 2 файлах с одинаковым кодом выводит по разному?  у вас тоже ошибка при выводе.

Comment: `
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file, expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) or heredoc end (T_END_HEREDOC) or ${ (T_DOLLAR_OPEN_CURLY_BRACES) or {$ (T_CURLY_OPEN) in D:\sites\mysite.local\www\rus\4\4\data types.php on line 59`

Comment: @ruben, у вас после `HERE;[space]` идет пробел, которого быть не должно

Comment: да, так и есть- пробел был лишним.

Comment: @ruben, рад что помог)